# Facebook page tab application $_POST values do not set

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I have a facebook application that consists of a form which values i want to store in my database.
my form method is POST, but in the action method, i cannot get any data sent be the form i use. below the form:

```
   <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="take_test.php" method="POST">    
<table>
<tr>
<td style = "padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 44px; font-size: 13px; color: #50729F;" >          <span style = "font-weight:bold;"> some question?</span>  <br>

 <fieldset class='radios'>
 <label class='label_radio' for="radio-01"><input id="radio-01" type="radio" name='q1' value='1'> some answer</label>
 <label class='label_radio' for="radio-02"><input id="radio-02" type="radio" name='q1' value='2'> some answer 2</label>
 <label class='label_radio' for="radio-03"><input id="radio-02" type="radio" name='q1' value='3'> some answer3 </label>
 </fieldset>
 </td>
```

```
<input type="text" name="signed_request" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['signed_request']; ?>">

<input type="submit" class="input_but" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and in the take_test.php i have

```
   if ($_POST) { 

        $b = $_POST['q1'];  
    }
```

but it says that index 'q1' is not defined and so $b is not set.
is there any special method for sending data through post in facebook page tabs?

thank you

Comment: Are you selecting one of the radio buttons when you submit the form?

Comment: Im not 100% sure because i don't remember ever using radio buttons (Prefer drop menus) but maybe its because they all have the same name?

Comment: no, they are groups of radios, thats why they have the same name

Comment: you have two of these `input id="radio-02"`

Comment: thank you DMCS. still did not solve the prob

Comment: what does print_f($_POST) show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by DMCS, you have two input elements with the same ID attribute.

```
 <label class='label_radio' for="radio-02"><input id="radio-02" type="radio" name='q1' value='2'> some answer 2</label>
 <label class='label_radio' for="radio-03"><input id="radio-02" type="radio" name='q1' value='3'> some answer3 </label>
```

Furthermore, the third radio button label is "for" a non-existent ID. Facebook may have strict HTML rules which prevent the form from working properly for errors such as these.